# Is there a JPA alternative to Hibernate's Session.reconnect

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Hibernate is able to disconnect and reconnect a Session from its underlying JDBC connection using `Session.disconnect` and `Session.reconnect(Connection)`.

Is there a way to achieve the same using only JPA? If not, is there an alternative pattern in JPA that allows me to keep a long running JPA session open while temporarily releasing the underlying JDBC connection.

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method in neither [EntityManagerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) nor [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html).

You can create a long running EntityManager with @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED) or EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(), but there are no methods for disconnect and reconnect of a Connection.

However, if after closing a EntityManger, you may create a new EntityManger and reconnect any detached entities with EntityManger.merge() (and then EntityManger.refresh() if desired).